# How can I make my slider to expand over 100% width of screen?

Tags: jquery

I am using slidjs jquery plugin (http://slidesjs.com/) for my website to show images in a slideshow. My images are 1200px x 450px (width x height). Everything is working fine expected my slider is not expanding over the full screen width. Here is a snapshot -

[image]

This is my script to execute this plugin -

```
// SlidesJS Required: Initialize SlidesJS with a jQuery doc ready
$('#slides').slidesjs({
    width: 1200,
    height: 450,
    navigation: {
        active: false,
        effect: "fade"
    },
    pagination: {
        active: false,
        effect: "fade"
    },
    play: {
        auto: true,
        effect: "fade",
        interval: 5000
    },
    effect: {
      fade: {
        speed: 1000
      }
    }
});
```

And this is the CSS -

```
    #slides {
      display: none
    }

    #slides .slidesjs-navigation {
      margin-top:3px;
    }

    #slides .slidesjs-previous {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    #slides .slidesjs-next {
      margin-right: 5px;
      float: left;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination {
      margin: 6px 0 0;
      float: right;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 1px;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a {
      display: block;
      width: 13px;
      height: 0;
      padding-top: 13px;
      background-image: url(/img/pagination.png);
      background-position: 0 0;
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a.active,
    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover.active {
      background-position: 0 -13px
    }

    .slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
      background-position: 0 -26px
    }

    #slides a:link,
    #slides a:visited {
      color: #333
    }

    #slides a:hover,
    #slides a:active {
      color: #9e2020
    }

    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden
    }

/* Prevent the slideshow from flashing on load */
#slides {
  display: none
}

/* Center the slideshow */
.container {
  margin: 0 auto
}

/* Show active item in the pagination */
.slidesjs-pagination .active {
  color:red;
}

/* Media quires for a responsive layout */

/* For tablets & smart phones */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  .container {
    width: auto
  }
}

/* For smartphones */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    width: auto
  }
}

/* For smaller displays like laptops */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  .container {
    width: 724px
  }
}

/* For larger displays */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px
  }
}
```

The required jQuery library, sliderjs plugin js and css files are also referenced. The only problem is the dimension of this slider. I want the slider to expand over my slider container which have black background. But I am not able to do that.

Comment: make the width 100% not 1200px

Comment: for which - in jquery code, but i tried it and plugin stopped working.

Comment: have you tried looking at the structure in developer tools and seeing if there's something you can target with CSS to set it 100%?

Comment: you want the slider to have 100% width? I mean this part in your jQuery `width: 1200` to be like `width: 100%`, right?

Comment: yes that's right but width: 100% doesn't work; it merely stops plugin to work.

Comment: i saw with developer tool e.g. with firebug and if i set the width of container to 100% then the images get distorted and responsiveness of this plugins also stops working.

Comment: can anyone please make jsfiddle of this plugin demo for 100% width so that i can get help from there?